# Can I use a hall sensor ammeter to measure current in several DC wires simultaneously?

Tags: power-supply, power, hall-effect

I would like to embed something [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BFJ5NV5L) into my LED application and measure the total current supplied (ideally I'd want to display watts but can't find such a device).

The problem is [my power supply](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/709-PSPA-1000-12) has several 12v outputs that I would use for different branches and I'd like to measure their total power used without tying them all into one, extra thick cable beforehand...

Would it work or would the magnetic fields interfere if I stuck all the wires through the hall sensor?

Comment: DS shows one output but paralleled terminals. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes.

Magnetic fields superpose so if you run multiple wires through the coil the induced currents will add together as you expect. You can even amplify the signal of a single wire simply by looping it back through the coil multiple times.

[image]

This effect is used in constructing transformers and inductors.

The manufacturer (or reseller) of the meter you referenced even points this out in their product application notes:

> Loop through sensor multiple times to strengthen signal. For example, if your current signal is only 0.2 Amps, you could loop the wire through the sensor 10 times and the signal would by 10X stronger and would appear as 2.0 Amps

#### However...

Magnetic fields are vector fields. They have both a phase and an amplitude. This means that the direction that the wire enters the coil and the timing of the signal in the wire both matter. If you simply turn the wire around after passing through the coil and pass back through -- the two fields will be completely out of phase and cancel each other.

In your case, measuring DC with the hall effect, as long as the power lines all originate from the same power supply, **and enter the coil from the same side**, it will work exactly as you expect, with the meter displaying the combined (additive) reading across all wires.

Comment: Ah great, thanks for the detailed explanation!